# Need a Web Based Code Repository, not a Source Control System

Tags: sharepoint, repository

My company uses TFS to manage source code.  We are looking for a way to share code examples and snippets between various teams to enable better collaboration.  Ideally, the submitter would be able to author a short article to go with the code.  Code just be pre-formatted HTML in the article, or be attached as a downloadable file.

So, need a non-source control, web-based, code repository.  Leaning towards SharePoint, but I'm sure there is something better out there.

Comment: Any Wiki-engine tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ending up going with a customized SharePoint wiki solution.